# How can I add a RangeBar to my preferences.xml?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm using the [`androidx Preferences library`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/package-summary.html) to implement my settings.

However unfortunately Android does not have a `RangeBar` with 2 thumbs, only a `SeekBarPreference` with 1 thumb.

What is the best simple way to go about creating my own `RangeBar`? I've tried multiple libraries such as: https://github.com/nickwinder/range-bar-preference and https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1756 and they simply don't compile.

For context, I'm trying to create a `RangeBar` between 1 and 99 which includes a min value and max value.

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <Preference
       android:title="Settings"
       android:key="settings_category"
       android:layout="@layout/preference_title"/>
    <SeekBarPreference
        android:layout="@layout/preference_widget_seekbar_override"
        app:showSeekBarValue="false"
        android:max="30"
        android:defaultValue="10"
        android:key="distance"
        android:title="Max distance (km)"/>

    <RangeBarPreference
        .../>
```

Comment: What's the issue with the compilation?

Comment: `RangeBarPreference` doesn't exist - I'm just writing that as a placeholder. I'd like to create my custom `RangeBarPreference` which extends `ProgressBar` @tynn